# My Fibonacci Formula (with combinatorics)

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

Hi I originally posted this on MathOverflow, and was told to post it here.
I'm a high school student, and was playing around with pascals triangle. and ended up taking (weird) diagonals. And I saw Fibonacci numbers, from the sum of the diagonals.

Pascall's triangle is just combinatorics. So I made a formula. I said that the nth Fibonacci number starts at 0. So $$F(0) = 1, F(1) = 1, F(2) = 2, F(3) = 3, F(4) = 5,\dots$$

My sum is this:
$F(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} {n-k\choose k}$

This means each diagonal wil lhave $\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1$ terms.

So $F(0) = {0\choose 0} = 1$
$F(1) = {1\choose 0} = 1$
$F(2) = {2\choose 0} + {1\choose 1} = 2$.....

I put together a python program that does this, and it seems to work.

Have I done something wrong?

What steps should I go through to prove it?

I don't know much maths stuff. Is this already a commonly known formula?

Thanks.

Comment: I like your intuition. Most logical one is by mathematical induction. There are most likely more "cute" proofs.

Comment: You've done nothing wrong, and the result is indeed correct. It seems to be known widely enough to have an entry on wikipedia, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Mathematics).

Comment: This formula is the first thing in the “Applications” section of the Wikipedia page, FWIW. The page uses “generating functions” to prove it, which might or might not be more advanced than you are looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: Try to use mathematical induction with the definition of Pascal's triangle. When you try to show $F(n) + F(n+1) = F(n+2)$ and see the numbers occur in each sum, you might be able to identify which terms in $F(n)$ and $F(n+1)$ add up to one in $F(n+2)$.

Comment: If you want to experiment more with Fibonacci numbers, try setting $F(0), F(1)$ to values different from $0,1$ and see what happens with the ratio of two consecutive numbers in the sequence as $n$ increases. You can also define your next element to be the sum of the three (or more!) previous elements, or even their weighted sum! Each sequence will produce its own unique spiral. There is a lot of room for experiment!

Comment: (The formula on the Wikipedia page is slightly different, because that page start with $F_0=0, F_1=1.$)